# Conditionally add site property using ARM templates

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have a situation where I sometimes want my site to have a hostNameSslStates property. I have been trying to figure out how to do this without having seperate deployments for sites with a hostNameSslState and sites without.

This is how I would add a site today, I then add slots, config, certifcates, roles etc so the total ARM file is much larger.

```
{
    "name": "[parameters('appServiceName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "AppService"
    },
    "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
    },
    "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": "[variables('siteConfig')]",
        "hostNameSslStates": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('websiteCustomDomainName')]",
            "sslState": "SniEnabled",
            "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint]",
            "toUpdate": true
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is that some app services does not have a custom domain and does not need a hostNameSslStates property and I am not able to find a solution to how to implement this in the template. I can have a variable that is "hostNameSslState" but I am not able to condition the property. If I could specify hostNameSslStates as a seperate resource then that would solve my issue but I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
"hostNameSslStates": "[if(something, variables('sslStuff'), json('[]'))]"
```

and then in your variables define `sslStuff`:

```
"sslStuff": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('websiteCustomDomainName')]",
        "sslState": "SniEnabled",
        "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint]",
        "toUpdate": true
    }
}
```

Comment: The json('[]') is a neat trick! Howervere - you cannot use the reference() functions in a variable. I ended up conditionally triggering the referncefunction and the putting the hostnamesslstate stuff in a nested template. Its ugly.

Comment: ah right, well, you can do that with the nested\linked template or just using an output, either way you should upvote\accept this answer as it helped you ;)